# How is a PE COFF loader suppposed to memory map in image sections given a section alignment (in the raw file) of 0x200?

Tags: windows, portable-executable

Usually, the OS page size is 4096 or 0x1000 and so the section offsets aren't at an easy point for memory mapping into memory.

Elf makes this easy with the program header data but there doesn't seem to be anything similar for the PE format.

So far, I have resorted to allocating memory and then reading in the file data into the sections but this doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Seems very unlikely, do distinguish between section alignment and file alignment.  Having a file alignment of 512 bytes isn't that unusual.  Requires multiple mmap views to map correctly.

Comment: Based on the documentation, you *can* create an image with a section alignment less than the page size.  But I think you'll find that Windows will refuse to load such an image, so it's probably OK if your loader rejects it too.  The default section alignment for the MS build tools is 4096.